# Is it possible to use bluetooth as proximity detector?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

*Actors*:

Server: is a rooted Android device, that never sleep (never goes in standby)

Client: is one of many non-rooted smartphone, Android or IOS

*Scenario*:

The server is fixed in a place.

Server need to know when some client is near, without user intervention, identifying that device.
The client is switched on but can be in standby (with screen off).

I can install custom app both to client and server.

*Target to achieve*:

When a client comes near the server, the server knows it, without user intervention.

Detection does not need user intervention, but maybe is possibile the first time that users has to do some configuration to register the server bluetooth.

*Questions*:

Is it possibile to achieve it?

Both for Android and IOS clients?

Which solutions does I have to implement?

*Thank you in advance*

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea but with ble you can do an advertisement with a packet of data.

- Have an app that advertises some data for the client app.
- Then on the server application receive these values by performing a ble scan.

Within this scan you can see the device address, scan record data(advertisement) and the RSSI. The rssi is the received power. From this you should be able to infer distance. As if the RSSI is lower then the device is further away thus a proximity detector. So if the RSSI is above a certain value add this device to a list to say they are in your detector range.

Comment: hello, the problem is not finding the range, any range would be ok, the problem is make it working with client in standby, since I think the app in standby can not act as active sender